Why does ffplay show lots of errors in the stream of security cameras?
Recently I've purchased and installed 4 security cameras and an NVR. In my room, I have a monitor with a Raspberry Pi 5 attached to show the 4 streams of the cameras as well. To do this, I have opened 4 terminals, each running the following command:
ffplay -left 0 -top 0 -x 960 -y 540 "rtsp://user:pass@camera-IP:port/videoSub"

Obviously with the correct left, top, IP and port parameters so the screen is divided in 4 sections.
This works fairly well, except there are lots of errors visible in the streams. Sometimes a camera goes gray for a few frames, sometimes I see a broken screen (like a broken JPG) so I'm assuming there is a corruption in the stream.
If I view the same streams on my PC (main streams and sub streams) via Foscam VMS (the software which came with the NVR), the streams are perfect.
My PC is connected to the same network as the Raspberry Pi, the cameras and the NVR, so I doubt there are network issues.
Because the monitor needs to show 4 camera's, I'm also using the sub streams (640x540 I believe) instead of the 8MP main streams.
Network and CPU usage to show the streams are next to negligible.
I tried to do the same on a laptop running Linux, with the exact same results.
Why doesn't the Raspberry Pi show these streams correctly? And, more important, how do I fix it so I get a decent image on my monitor?
Thanks!

What Error Messages did you get?

@Christoph After a lot of trial and error, I gave up and added the -rtsp_transport tcp flag to the command which improved performance immensly. Now, only one or two cameras stop showing the stream approximately once a day. I'll add the flag as an answer to this question and open another question for a solution to this new problem, as I'm looking for a way to solve it that is quite different than this. Thanks for trying to help though!

As mentioned in a comment/reply to @Christoph, I finally gave up and added the -rtsp_transport tcp flag to the command line.
This has improved reliability immensely! Whereas in the original situation I couldn't get a decent image for more than a minute (at best!), now the images are perfect and crystal clear all of the time.
